# First Link Found but cant find the second one? (Python, bs4)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I have a bunch of links I wanna download from using wget and bs4 and before I use wget to download I need to scrape the download link from the website. But im having an issue where it find's the first actual download link but not the second.

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os

links = open('links.txt', 'r') 
count = 0

while True:
    count += 1
    line = links.readline()
    if not line: 
        break
    print("Line{}: {}".format(count, line.strip()))
    source = requests.get(line)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text,'lxml')
    Download = soup.find(id="download-url", href=True)
    print(Download.get('href'))
```

And The Output:

```
Line1: (Download Link Here)
(Download URL Here)
Line2: (Download Link Here)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Downloads\Downloader\Downloads\download.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(Download.get('href'))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: `1`. `Download` this is invalid `Python` variable, check [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names), `2`. you've to `print(download)` and check the content of it firstly. `3`. the solution is to use `requests.get(download.get("href"))` .. but why you not make your life easier by `download = soup.find(id="download-url", href=True).get("href")`. and I've to tell you if your end goal is to `print(requests.get(download.get("href")))` as the way you are doing. you are just printing the response

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη - it's not "invalid" to capitalize a Python variable, it's just not standard (PEP 8) style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If BeautifulSoup isn't finding any element with an id of `download-url`, the likely explanation is that there is no such element in the source that was fetched.

Possible reasons:

- There's a typo in the URL you're fetching and you're parsing a 404 page
- The page requires auth, which you forgot because you're logged into it via your browser
- The page you're hitting does UA sniffing and is returning different content to `requests` than to a normal browser
- The page you're hitting does rate limiting and you've hit it too many times with your script

In any case, the answer is the same: **write your code so that it confirms the presence of the element it depends on, and gives you troubleshooting information if it fails.** It could print the source of the page, for instance, and/or the response code, and/or the content of some other element you know is on the page.

Scraping is messy business. Special-casing and preparing for unexpected breakage is part of the work.